# fire different UIlocalnotification for set number of days

Tags: ios, objective-c, uilocalnotification

I have an app that when the user opens the app for the first time, I save the date and I want to send local notifications everyday at a certain time for 30 days. Everyday needs to be different. Each message is a reminder of that days event.

In Appdelegate I set the date to the current time then call a method

```
- (void)applicationDidEnterBackground:(UIApplication *)application {

NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter1 = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[dateFormatter1 setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"];
NSDate *date = [NSDate date];
NSLog(@"date : %@",date);

NSTimeZone *currentTimeZone = [NSTimeZone localTimeZone]; // <- Local time zone
NSTimeZone *utcTimeZone = [NSTimeZone timeZoneWithAbbreviation:@"UTC"];

NSInteger currentGMTOffset = [currentTimeZone secondsFromGMTForDate:date];
NSInteger gmtOffset = [utcTimeZone secondsFromGMTForDate:date];
NSTimeInterval gmtInterval = currentGMTOffset - gmtOffset;

NSDate *destinationDate = [[NSDate alloc] initWithTimeInterval:gmtInterval    sinceDate:date];
NSLog(@"date : %@",destinationDate);

[self loadNotif:destinationDate];

}
```

in the loadNotif method is where I have a for loop that adds one day to the current date and and calls my schedulenotificatons method

```
-(void)loadNotif:(NSDate *)notifDate {
 NSLog(@" date %@", notifDate);
NSString *alertMSG = @"";

NSDateComponents *dayComponent = [[NSDateComponents alloc] init];
    for (int i = 0; i <= 3; i++) {


dayComponent.second = i;
    if (i == 0) {
        alertMSG = @"Checkout Today's Video! Sustainable Posture!";
    } else if (i == 1) {
        alertMSG = @"Checkout Today's Video! Forward Head!";
    } else if (i == 2) {
        alertMSG = @"Checkout Today's Video! Neck Position!";
    } else if (i == 3) {
        alertMSG = @"Checkout Today's Video! Shoulder Position!";
    } 

  notifDate = [notifDate dateByAddingTimeInterval:5];
    [self scheduleNotificationForDate:notifDate AlertBody:alertMSG ActionButtonTitle:@"30 Day Posture Challenge" NotificationID:alertMSG];

NSLog(@"nextDate: %@ ... %@", notifDate, alertMSG);
 }
}
```

for test purposes i am only adding 5 seconds to the date to see if they are working.

```
-(void) scheduleNotificationForDate:(NSDate *)date AlertBody:(NSString *)alertBody ActionButtonTitle:(NSString *)actionButtonTitle NotificationID:(NSString *)notificationID{
UILocalNotification *localNotification = [[UILocalNotification alloc] init];

NSLog(@"firedate %@", date);

localNotification.fireDate = date;
localNotification.timeZone = [NSTimeZone localTimeZone];
localNotification.alertBody = alertBody;
localNotification.alertAction = actionButtonTitle;
localNotification.soundName=UILocalNotificationDefaultSoundName;

localNotification.applicationIconBadgeNumber= + 1;

NSDictionary *infoDict = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObject:notificationID forKey:@"notifID"];
localNotification.userInfo = infoDict;

[[UIApplication sharedApplication] scheduleLocalNotification:localNotification];

}
```

The issue I am having is all the notification fire at the same time. Any clue why this is happening?

Comment: What do the log messages say?

Comment: The log messages show that the firedate works correctly. 5 seconds added each loop 2016-10-20 20:10:41.328  firedate 2016-10-20 20:10:46 +0000
firedate 2016-10-20 20:10:51 +0000

Comment: The only thing I can think of is maybe 5 seconds is just too fine-grained. The system is delivering these things on your behalf so it makes a judgment about how to clump them together. So it may be combining them on purpose. So, even though it will be a pain, put them a minute apart and see how you go.

Comment: Also, just checking — you do know that UILocalNotification is deprecated in iOS 10, right?

Comment: I was wondering that too. I will try it now.

Comment: Yeah I was not building this for 10 but probably should. I tried with minute and same result. maybe its a simulator thing? will try on device now.

Comment: Grasping at straws here... Maybe it has something to do with the fact that you are doing this in `applicationDidEnterBackground`? Try just running the "schedule 3 notifications" code in response to a button press and then hit the home button to background the app yourself.

Comment: By the way, all that time zone and GMT stuff is complete nonsense and a waste of your time. You are seriously over-thinking this. `[NSDate new]` is now. NSDate time interval since now is five seconds from now. That's all you need to know or do.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/126284/discussion-between-mike-owens-and-matt).

Answer (score 0):

I'm going to go out on a limb and suggest that all that jiggery-pokery with GMT and time zones is what's messing you up. I don't know what it's supposed to do but it makes my eyes go crossed. To schedule a local notification five seconds from now is a one-liner:

```
ln.fireDate = [NSDate dateWithTimeIntervalSinceNow:15];
```

I would suggest that you stick with that sort of thing. Just pass a number of seconds to your notification scheduler.